# Objects of an array is displaying an error "Java returned: 1" when using setters (or anything) with it

Tags: java, arrays, loops, class, object

I'm very new to programming.
I have a main class and another class, myClass.
When I run the program there is an error in the main class.
It is supposed to be an array of objects and the loop is supposed to set/change/declare things for each object.

Code from the main class:

```
myClass[] myObj= new myClass[100];

for(int i = 0; i<amount;i++){
myObj[i].setF(sc.next());
myObj[i].setG(sc.next());
myObj[i].myMethod[0]=sc.nextInt();
myObj[i].myMethod[1]=sc.nextInt();
myObj[i].myMethod[2]=sc.nextInt();
}
```

error says line says "*Java returned: 1*" and the links redirect me to:   `<java classname="@{classname}" dir="${work.dir}" failonerror="${java.failonerror}" fork="true" jvm="${platform.java}">`

In the *myObj* class there are no issues, and from what I can tell trough testing it, the error is specifically coming from myObj[i].
I can't figure out how to fix it though.

Comment: You have to initialize your class just after for loop like `myObj[i] = new myClass();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not initializing your array elements before using them. You would need to define a constructor for your class like this(Note that Java class names should always start with uppercase):

```java
// With your current approach you would at least need to allocate memory for member array
public MyClass() {
    this.myMethod = new int[3];
}

or

// You can also use a constructor like this
public MyClass(String f, String g, int[] methodArr) {
    this.f = f;
    this.g = g;
    this.myMethod = methodArr;
}
```

Then you should be able to call it from your driver method like this:

Using No argument constructor:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    myObj[i] = new MyClass();

    myObj[i].setF(sc.next());
    myObj[i].setG(sc.next());
    myObj[i].myMethod[0] = sc.nextInt();
    myObj[i].myMethod[1] = sc.nextInt();
    myObj[i].myMethod[2] = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Using argument constructor:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    int[] myMethodArr = new int[3];

    String fInput = sc.next();
    String gInput = sc.next();
    myMethodArr[0] = sc.nextInt();
    myMethodArr[1] = sc.nextInt();
    myMethodArr[2] = sc.nextInt();
    
    myObj[i] = new MyClass(fInput, gInput, myMethodArr);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very clear. I decided to make a constructor since I wasn't able to make it work the first way. When I tried to make a constructor before, I didn't realize I needed to use this.f etc  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

In Java when you create an array, you are only creating an array of references. This means that your object instances are not automatically there.

The effect of this fact is that you have to create your array first, and then populate it with references to objects, which you also have to create. Here is how to do that:

```
myClass[] myObj= new myClass[100];

for(int i = 0; i<amount;i++){
    myObj[i] = new myClass(); // here you populate the array with instances
    myObj[i].setF(sc.next());
    myObj[i].setG(sc.next());
    myObj[i].myMethod[0]=sc.nextInt();
    myObj[i].myMethod[1]=sc.nextInt();
    myObj[i].myMethod[2]=sc.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but I'm still having issues. In myClass do I need to have myClass set as a constructor in order for this to work? This worked when I did it that way but it caused me other problems so I would rather do it line by line if possible.